# Agrupar dados de tabela com duas colunas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Pois bem, estou em uma incognita que gostaria de resolver direto na query SQL, vejam esse exemplo suposto:

```
TIPO | DE | IDENTIFICADOR
-------------------------
001  | 23 | 9
001  | 44 | 9
001  | 23 | 8
002  | 11 | 11
```

O meu desejo é **agrupar** os dados afim de facilitar a interpretação, nesse caso ele deveria agrupar dados de mesmo *TIPO* e *IDENTIFICADOR*, de forma que eu saiba os *DE* para exibir para o usuário.

O retorno seria algo como:

```
2 dados de 23, 24 sobre o identificador 9
1 dado de 23 sobre o identificador 8
1 dado de 11 sobre o identificador 11
```

quais seriam os meios para realizar isto direto na query, possibilitando um retorno semelhante ao exemplificado?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma parte da sua query, veja ela funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe175e/4

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `tipo` varchar(10),
  `de`  varchar(10),
  `identificador` varchar (10)
);

INSERT INTO `teste` (`tipo`,`de`, `identificador`) VALUES
('001','23', '9'),
('001','44', '9'),
('001','23', '8'),
('002','11', '11');

SELECT identificador, GROUP_CONCAT(de ORDER BY de ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS campo
FROM teste
GROUP BY identificador
```

A parte de contar quantos tem de cada vou deixar pra você fazer ;-)

Comment: Eh impressionante como um pouquinho de codigo funcionando e com exemplo,  ajuda a gente a estudar e entender mais!   eu tambem estava precisando de algo semelhante!  Obrigada @Michelle Akemi!

Comment: De nada, @CamilaYamamoto! Adoro saber que ajudei. Eu que agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Caso queira obter como dados separados:

```
SELECT COUNT(tipo) as quantidade,
       identificador,
       GROUP_CONCAT(de ORDER BY de SEPARATOR ', ') AS dados
  FROM tabela
 GROUP BY tipo,
          identificador
```

Ou se quiser obter já com o texto que foi proposto:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(tipo), ' dados de ', GROUP_CONCAT(de ORDER BY de SEPARATOR ', '), ' sobre o identificador ', identificador) AS texto
  FROM tabela
 GROUP BY tipo,
          identificador
```

Onde:

- `COUNT` conta as ocorrências de uma linha baseada na função de agrupamento (`GROUP BY`);
- `CONCAT` concatena os campos listados (incluí o texto entre `'`);
- `GROUP_CONCAT` concatena as colunas listas baseado na função de agrupamento.

> [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement. The result is a [`BIGINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) value.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a contagem numérica de valores não-NULOS da expressão na linha selecionada pela cláusula [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). O resultado é um valor [`BIGINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

---

> [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a string resultante da concatenação dos argumentos.

---

> [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
>
> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

Em tradução livre:

> Essa função retorna a string resultante da concatenação de valores não-NULOS de um grupo.